# javascript function only works with first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

I have an xsl file and I was able to get it to display the title in the on click function but I can only get the first title to be shown the others stay hidden, and the first title is shown no matter what button calls the function. the function also doesn't hide the button after it is pressed so there must be something wrong with the function and the specific lines? also I'm opening this with internet explorer..

```
    <script language="javascript">
      function ShowTitle(title, btn)
      {
      document.getElementById("title").style.display = 'inline'
      title.style.display = 'inline'
      btn.style.display = 'none'
      }
    </script>

    <body>

      <xsl:for-each select="/questions/question/movie[position() >1]">

        <div style="background-color:tan;color:black;">
          <span style="font-weight:bold">In What Movie Did They Say:
            <xsl:value-of select="quote"/> -
          </span>
          <input type="button" value="Show title" onclick="ShowTitle('title', this)"></input>
          <span id="title" style="display:none">
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/></span>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:1em;font-size:15pt">
        </div>
        <br/>

      </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: id must be unique in an HTML document. i.e. you cannot have two elements on the page with the same id, it will always just get the first one. Use classes instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by OJay, the issue is that you are trying to retrieve elements by `id` when there are multiple elements being generated with this `id` by your XSL.

You should change this part of your html

```
<div style="background-color:tan;color:black;">
  <span style="font-weight:bold">In What Movie Did They Say:
    <xsl:value-of select="quote"/> -
  </span>
  <input type="button" value="Show title" onclick="ShowTitle(this)"></input>
  <span class="title" style="display:none">
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

You can then update your `ShowTitle` method as follows:

```
function ShowTitle(btn) {
    // get the btn's parent element. In this case the div
    var btnParentDiv = btn.parentElement;  

    // use getElementsByClassName to retrieve the title
    // getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements. 
    // In this case this is an array of length == 1
    // we're just interested in the first result, so get it immediately
    var divTitleElement = btnParentDiv.getElementsByClassName('title')[0];


    // Set the selected element to be visible
    divTitleElement.style.display = 'inline'

    // hide the button as before        
    btn.style.display = 'none'
}
```

This code can be shortened but I've split some steps up to include explanations